# Types of parameters 'action' and 'action' are incompatible

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-redux

I'm just starting with react redux with Typescript (v 2.6.1) and I have been working on a little app from the VS 2017 boilerplate. At my fifth View, I see that for some reason I have problems in creating actions. Basically in the code below that is a very simplified code, that should work very easily, if I remove the multiplier in the Multiply action works but when I add the multiplier doesn't. I can't figure it out.

Trying to simplify and fix it, I see that it's not even working the following code, which should be pretty straighforward.

```
import { AppThunkAction } from "ClientApp/store";
import { Action, Reducer } from 'redux';
import { fetch, addTask } from 'domain-task';
import update from 'immutability-helper';

// The top-level state object
export interface CompoundState {
    value: number,
}

export interface AddAction  {
    type: 'ADD_ACTION',
    addend:number
}

export interface MultiplyAction {
    type: 'MULTIPLY_ACTION',
    multiplier:number
}

type KnownAction = AddAction | MultiplyAction
export const actionCreators = {
    add: (addend): AppThunkAction<AddAction> => (dispatch, getState) => {
        dispatch({ type: 'ADD_ACTION', addend: addend })
    },
    multiply: (multiplier): AppThunkAction<MultiplyAction> => (dispatch, getState) => {
        dispatch({ type: 'MULTIPLY_ACTION', multiplier: multiplier })
    },
}

const unloadedState: CompoundState =
{
    value: 0,
};
export const reducer: Reducer<CompoundState> = (state: CompoundState, action: KnownAction) => {

    switch (action.type) {
        case 'ADD_ACTION':
            return update(state, {
                value: {
                    $set: state.value + action.addend
                }
            });
        case 'MULTIPLY_ACTION':
            return update(state, {
                value: {
                    $set: state.value * action.multiplier
                }
            });

    }
    return state || unloadedState;
};
```

What do you think?

Answer (score 4):

```
export const reducer: Reducer<CompoundState> = (state: CompoundState, incomingAction: Action) => {
    const action = incomingAction as KnownAction;
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'ADD_ACTION':
            return update(state, {
                value: {
                    $set: state.value +1
                }
            });
        case 'MULTIPLY_ACTION':
            return update(state, {
                value: {
                    $set: state.value * 2
                }
            });

    }
    return state || unloadedState;
};
```

Hope it can help somebody.

Comment: It works!! I've been searching for hours and this is the only valid solution. So it's basically not restricting action type on `incomingAction` in arg, and cast that to our own action type by `const action = incomingAction as KnownAction;`. I wonder if this is the best practice since I see no where doing this. But this is the only way to let reducer typing work with `combineReducers`. I feel documentation for redux + typescript is still very limited at this point. If I figured it out, I'd definitely want to write one.

Comment: Pretty big resource for using Redux w/ TypeScript over here: https://github.com/piotrwitek/react-redux-typescript-guide As a sidenote while this *works* in that it doesn't give you any errors, that's only because it's using a cast which subverts the type-system. I'm going to keep trying to figure out the root cause and how to solve this the "right" way.

Comment: Ok after a *bunch* of digging around, if the error goes away when you add `strictFunctionTypes: false` to your `tsconfig.json` then it seems to be a bug with the way the typings are set up to infer the state when declaring reducers. This PR is currently open and will hopefully fix it: https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/pull/3679